# Pandas search one column value for string value in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to search a dataframe column for the string value of another column.  This is a same row search.   My data looks like:

```
Column1     Column2
 "Jimmy"   "His name is Jimmy"
 "James"    "His name is Joe"
 "John"     NaN
```

current non-working code:
np.where(df["Column2"].isindf["Column1"], 'Y', 'N')

Results would be 1st row True, others false
Really appreciate any assistance.
'''

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
df['out'] = ['Y' if pd.notna(a) and pd.notna(b) 
                 and a in b else 'N'
             for a,b in zip(df['Column1'], df['Column2'])]
```

Output:

```
  Column1            Column2 out
0   Jimmy  His name is Jimmy   Y
1   James    His name is Joe   N
2    John                NaN   N
```

If you want a boolean:

```
df['out'] = [pd.notna(a) and pd.notna(b) and a in b
             for a,b in zip(df['Column1'], df['Column2'])]
```

Output:

```
  Column1            Column2    out
0   Jimmy  His name is Jimmy   True
1   James    His name is Joe  False
2    John                NaN  False
```